# How do I access a specific pd.DataFrame column when the columns are not named

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am using the following syntax:

```
    series.str.split(pat=delimiter, expand=True)
```

To split a series into a DataFrme with three columns.  However, the columns are not named and thus I having difficulty accessing the columns.  I am interested in the second and third columns.  How to I access them?

Comment: Can you provide sample inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: Yes, is this before the split operation or after?

Comment: It is after the split operation. The resulting data frame from the split gives me a DF with unnamed columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the column names, assuming df is your dataframe

```
df.columns = ['column1' , 'column2' , 'column3']
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to use:

```
df.iloc[:,0] #grabs all rows, of the first column
df.iloc[:,1] #grabs all rows, of the second column
```

etc. etc.